# jquery clone an input doesn't see changes to the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form with hidden inputs.

I .clone() them and show them to the user in a .dialog().

The user makes some changes and i use .val() to change the hidden fields.

However the next time i clone the form(without reloading the page) i have the initial values again, and never the updates ones.

There seems to be this weird bug/result? see http://jsfiddle.net/YvBfP/  (broken for visible input too)

```
$(this).closest('td').find('button').click( function ()
{
    var d = $('#pagamento_anticipato').html();

    $(d).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        close: function( event, ui ) {
                var importo = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').val();
                var descrizione = $(this).find('textarea').val();
                var select = $(this).find('select').val();
                $(this).remove();

                $('#pagamento_anticipato').find('input[id="importo"]').val( importo );
                $('#pagamento_anticipato').find('#descrizione').val( descrizione );
                $('#pagamento_anticipato').find('#tipo').find('option[value="' + select + '"]').attr('selected', true);

            }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think you can change the value of div#money, but you can't modify its original html code by jquery. Any understandings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

using [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) sets/gets the current value and not the attribute for the element.

```
$(element).val(value) // sets current value
$(element).val() // <-- will always return the current value
```

to change the attribute you have to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(element).attr('value',value)
```

Then you will see the change in the HTML

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/bJjjw/

**EDIT:**

Just found out this doesn't work with jQuery 1.5.x and lower.. tested it with jQuery 1.6.0+ and it worked fine

Comment: Doesnt work if you change original value i.e to 3000  http://jsfiddle.net/N2npH/1/  and no, i didnt downvoted

Comment: @roasted ah.. it just doesn't work with jQuery 1.5 :/  It works fine with jQuery 1.6+

Comment: This behaviour was changed in jQuery 1.6 - see [Properties and Attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: ah so it is .attr('value', v) for input, .text() for textarea, and .attr('selected', 'selected') for select, i thought jQuery is suppose to save time xD

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the value property of the input but checking to see if the value attribute has changed. To see the elements value use `.val()` don't check its html. However if you need to change the  elements value attribute use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute)

```
$('#money')[0].setAttribute('value', 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YvBfP/4/